# What's the best way to implement news system without using wordpress?

Tags: php, wysiwyg, content-management

I'm a little afraid of using Wordpress because of his connotation "all made", plus my website is 100% hand coded, actually, i use the phpBB but it's not what I want cause visitors have to go out of the website to go to the forum to see the news.

**So how/what can I do to have my own news system management (publish/review/moderate comments)....**

Are there tools (i mean except WYSIWYG) / PHP class I can use to implement myself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with a lot of pre-built CMS these days is that they all started out small and overtime eventually grew into bloated piece of software that has more features that an average site will ever need.

Make a list of common features you will need and begin coding.  Start off with the basic CRUD system (Create/Read/Update/Delete) and start adding components as you need them.

And there also lot of 3rd party extensions available don't end up re-inventing the wheel.

- [jQuery](http://jquery.com) - Javascript
- [Smarty](http://smarty.net) - Templating to separate source and design
- [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) - Sending mail
- [Zend](http://zend.com) - Development framework

And I am sure there are lots more.

As a developer there's nothing more comforting than knowing you have full control over the code that you are running.

Comment: side-note: you might not need templating

Comment: Templating is not necessary but it can make your life easier by separating code from design.

Nothing worse than seeing code with echo and print all over the place.

I couldn't believe that's how Wordpress' code looks; so disgusting.

Answer (score 3):

Go ahead, write it yourself! A simple CMS is made up of only a dozen or so files, and only requires PHP and MySQL. My blog engine, which runs, azabani.com, is all hand-written code that took me a couple of days to write.

Comment: +1 I agree: if you are skilled enough to write it yourself, it's the best solution. And the skills needed are really small if you don't want anything complex.

Comment: i think i have the skill but is there any website you would recommand to avoid that i forget features or i make mistakes. Because writing your own cms is ok when you already know what to do :P when not, it's more complicated. Thanks ;)

Comment: *Never forget to quote and escape input to MySQL* or just use `mysqli` - a big security issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it yourself but if you prefer to use prebuilt tools there are lots of open source CMS' that you can intergrate into your site.

http://php.opensourcecms.com/

As Delan said though, a simple system for news and comments is pretty simple to implement yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the fastest way would be to install wordpress (if you werre interested in this cms in the first place) but use a posting widget to actually show the post content within your site.
If you wanted to stick with the hand coded theme of your site, maybe use one of the dozens of tutorials for example:
http://codegrrl.com/category/tutorials/build-a-blog

Comment: in fact i have some pre-made ideas on wordpress, to me, it's like an entire website all made (login system, content manager..), but i just need a news manager system. So maybe i'm wrong with wordpress and i can use it , just tell me :P